# why does a thread sometimes hang in waitfor?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

In my application I use thread based tasks. They work fine but sometimes they hang the application. In the code below `procedure Stop` sometimes hangs in the `WaitFor` procedure. That is because the `FStopEvent.SetEvent` not always appears to function.

During a normal execution the thread enters the `Execute` procedure, executes the `OnWork` procedure until `Stop` is called (which sets `Terminated`), then does some postprocessing and then exits. That is the signal for `WaitFor` to quit and everybody is happy. In my usage this occurs because the task is destroyed. In that case the destructor of the base class is called which calls `Stop`.

In some cases this does not work. `Execute` is entered correctly, the `OnWork` procedure calls are executed ok but there is no reaction on the `FStopEvent.SetEvent`. There has been no crash (the statement at the `except` is not executed) just nothing. The program hangs because the WaitFor does not return. With debug DCU's I can trace this back to the `WaitFor` in unit `Classes` where the program hangs at `WaitForSingleObject(H[0], INFINITE);`. The `OnWork` callback is the same.

The OnBeforeWork and OnAfterWork procedures are nil. `MaxLoops = -1` and `FreeOnTerminate = False`. I am quite desperate, hope that somebody has a way out.

**EDIT 1:** The `WaitFor` I am talking about occurs in class `TEvent_Driven_Task` listed below. Because this class is derived from class `TSimple_Task` I have added this class for completeness.

**EDIT 2:** `Application.ProcessMessages` has been removed from `TSimple_Task.Stop` as Marjan Venema remarked that this might cause a problem. The outcomes are identical (the program hangs in the `WaitFor`).

```
unit Parallel_Event_Task;

interface

uses Forms, Windows, Classes, SysUtils, SyncObjs,
     Parallel_Simple_Task;

type
   TEvent_Driven_Task = class (TSimple_Task)
   private
      FWorkEvent: TEvent; // Event signalling that some work should be done

   public
      constructor Create (work: TNotifyEvent; CreateSuspended: boolean = False;
                     max: Int32 = 1;
                     before: TNotifyEvent = nil; after: TNotifyEvent = nil;
                     terminate: boolean = True; task: integer = 1); override;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Activate (work: TNotifyEvent = nil);
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure Stop; override;
      procedure Release; override;
   end; // Class: TEvent_Driven_Task //

implementation

constructor TEvent_Driven_Task.Create
(
   work: TNotifyEvent;        // Work to do in Execute loop
   CreateSuspended: boolean = False; // False = start now, True = use Start
   max: Int32 = 1;            // Max loops of Execute loop, negative = infinite loop
   before: TNotifyEvent = nil;// Called before Execute loop
   after: TNotifyEvent = nil; // Called after Execute loop
   terminate: boolean = True; // When true free the task on termination
   task: integer = 1          // Task ID
);
begin
   inherited Create (work, CreateSuspended, max, before, after, terminate, task);

   FWorkEvent := TEvent.Create (nil, False,  False, '');
end; // Create //

Destructor TEvent_Driven_Task.Destroy;
begin
   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //

procedure TEvent_Driven_Task.Activate (work: TNotifyEvent = nil);
begin
   if Assigned (work) then OnWork := work;
   FWorkEvent.SetEvent;
end; // Activate //

// Execute calls event handler OnWork in a while loop.
// Before the loop is entered, OnBeforeWork is executed, after: OnAfterWork.
procedure TEvent_Driven_Task.Execute;
var two: TWOHandleArray;
    pwo: PWOHandleArray;
    ret: DWORD;
begin
   pwo := @two;
   pwo [0] := FWorkEvent.Handle;
   pwo [1] := FStopEvent.Handle;
   NameThreadForDebugging (AnsiString (FTaskName));
   FLoop := 0;
   try
      if Assigned (OnBeforeWork) then OnBeforeWork (Self);
      while (not Terminated) and (Loop <> Max_Loops) do
      begin
         FLoop := FLoop + 1;
         ret := WaitForMultipleObjects (2, pwo, FALSE, INFINITE);
         if ret = WAIT_FAILED then Break;
         case ret of
            WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 0: if Assigned (OnWork) then OnWork (Self);
            WAIT_OBJECT_0 + 1: Terminate;
         end; // case
      end; // while
      if Assigned (OnAfterWork) then OnAfterWork (Self);

// Intercept and ignore the interruption but keep the message
   except
      on e: exception do FError_Mess := e.Message;
   end; // try..except
end; // Execute //

procedure TEvent_Driven_Task.Stop;
begin
   Terminate;
   FStopEvent.SetEvent;
   if not FreeOnTerminate
      then WaitFor;
end; // Stop //

procedure TEvent_Driven_Task.Release;
begin
   inherited Release;

   FWorkEvent.Free;
end; // Release //

end. // Unit: Parallel_Simple_Task //
```

============= Base class =======================

```
unit Parallel_Simple_Task;

interface

uses Windows, Classes, SysUtils, SyncObjs, Forms;

type
   TSimple_Task = class (TThread)
   protected
      FStopEvent: TEvent;           // Event signalling that the thread has to terminate, set by Stop
      FTaskID: integer;             // Task sequence number
      FTaskName: string;            // Task name
      FLoop: integer;               // Indicates number of times Work has been processed
      FMax_Loops: integer;          // Maximum # of iterations
      FError_Mess: string;          // Error message if an exception occurred, else empty
      FOnBeforeWork:  TNotifyEvent; // Event to be called just before thread loop is entered
      FOnWork:        TNotifyEvent; // Event caled in Execute loop
      FOnAfterWork:   TNotifyEvent; // Event to be called just after thread loop is finished

      procedure set_name (value: string);

   public
      constructor Create (work: TNotifyEvent; CreateSuspended: boolean = False; max: Int32 = 1;
                     before: TNotifyEvent = nil; after: TNotifyEvent = nil;
                     terminate: boolean = True; task: integer = 1); reintroduce; virtual;
      destructor Destroy; override;
      procedure Execute; override;
      procedure Stop; virtual;
      procedure Release; virtual;

      property TaskID: integer read FTaskID;
      property TaskName: string read FTaskName write set_name;
      property Loop: integer read FLoop;
      property Max_Loops: integer read FMax_Loops write FMax_Loops;
      property OnBeforeWork:  TNotifyEvent read FOnBeforeWork  write FOnBeforeWork;
      property OnWork:        TNotifyEvent read FOnWork        write FOnWork;
      property OnAfterWork:   TNotifyEvent read FOnAfterWork   write FOnAfterWork;
   end; // Class: TSimple_Task //

implementation

constructor TSimple_Task.Create
(
   work: TNotifyEvent;        // Work to do in Execute loop
   CreateSuspended: boolean = False; // False = start now, True = use Start
   max: Int32 = 1;            // Max loops of Execute loop
   before: TNotifyEvent = nil;// Called before Execute loop
   after: TNotifyEvent = nil; // Called after Execute loop
   terminate: boolean = True; // When true free the task on termination
   task: integer = 1          // Task ID
);
begin
// The thread will only be started when this constructor ends.
   inherited Create (CreateSuspended);

   FStopEvent        := TEvent.Create (nil, True,  False, '');
   FError_Mess       := '';
   FTaskID           := task;
   FTaskName         := '';
   Max_Loops         := max;
   OnBeforeWork      := before;
   OnWork            := work;
   OnAfterWork       := after;
   FreeOnTerminate   := terminate;
end; // Create //

destructor TSimple_Task.Destroy;
begin
   Stop;
   Release;

   inherited Destroy;
end; // Destroy //

// Execute calls event handler OnWork in a while loop.
// Before the loop is entered, OnBeforeWork is executed, after: OnAfterWork.
procedure TSimple_Task.Execute;
var ret: DWORD;
begin
   try
      NameThreadForDebugging (AnsiString (FTaskName));

      FLoop := 0;
      if Assigned (OnBeforeWork) then OnBeforeWork (Self);
      while (not Terminated) and (FLoop <> Max_Loops) do
      begin
         ret := WaitForSingleObject (FStopEvent.Handle, 0);
         if ret = WAIT_OBJECT_0 then
         begin
            Terminate;
         end else
         begin
            if Assigned (OnWork) then OnWork (Self);
            FLoop := FLoop + 1;
         end; // if
      end; // while
      if not Terminated and Assigned (OnAfterWork) then OnAfterWork (Self);
// Intercept and ignore the interruption but keep the message
   except
      on e: exception do FError_Mess := e.Message;
   end; // try..except
end; // Execute //

procedure TSimple_Task.Stop;
begin
   Terminate;
   FStopEvent.SetEvent;
   if not FreeOnTerminate
      then WaitFor;
end; // Stop //

procedure TSimple_Task.Release;
begin
   FStopEvent.Free;
end; // Release //

procedure TSimple_Task.set_name (value: string);
begin
   FTaskName := value;
end; // set_name //

end. // Unit: Parallel_Simple_Task //
```

Comment: Which Execute method is running? You posted two. Which one is it? What is the thread that is blocked doing? What does the debugger tell you? The threads window of modern Delphis will tell you what it is blocking on.

Comment: It is the thread in TEvent_Driven_Task.

Comment: The debugger does not tell me much if you mean the thread status. All threads are stopped and all statuses are unknown, there is no wait chain. That was also the state during execution, but that could be caused because the OnWork routine does not require much execution time. Most of the time this thread is waiting for FWorkEvent to be triggered.

Comment: You have an `Application.ProcessMessages` in the `TSimple_Task.Stop` procedure. That statement itself is not necessarily the problem, but it is indicative of interactions between the main (gui) thread and your workers. And that could certainly throw a spanner in the works. I have had the honour of debugging some very hard "hang" issues which in the end traced back to a thread waiting for something that depends on a message being handled while a(nother) earlier message being processed in the main thread is waiting for something held by the thread.

Comment: @Marjan, that was one of my desperate measures to try whether the `FStopEvent.SetEvent` was waiting to be processed. Stupid of course because when the code works (in most of the cases) there was no `Application.ProcessMessages` present. Thanks for pointing it out to me, I had forgotten to delete it. Other 'you never know' measures are duplicating `Stop` at the `TEvent_Driven_Task` level and introducing a `Destroy` that is not strictly necessary.

Comment: @MarjanVenema - you may well be right. The line that the OP says is hanging is only executed if the 'if GetCurrentThreadID = MainThreadID' chack in 'classes' fails, presumably meaning that 'Stop' is not called on the main GUI thread, which further means that the dreaded 'Application.ProcessMessages' is being called from a non-GUI thread.

Comment: ..or, it may just be some debug that the OP left in... :)

Comment: It was just some debug. I edited the question to reflect this fact. This issue is haunting me since September and in fact the only 'unsolvable' issue yet. I have never hoped so much people pointing out my errors as I have now :-)

Comment: Well, with continual create/terminate/destroy, there just so many ways for things to go wrong.  For instance, what happens if setting the 'terminated' flag causes the work thread to actually terminate before the call to 'TThread.WaitFor' is made?  The thread handle is invalid.  There are surely others.  All these hard-waits like TThread.WaitFor, TThread.Synchronize are just lurking deadlocks looking for a way out.

Comment: @MartinJames, my problem here is that the Thread does *not* terminate, it simply does not react on a `FStop_Event.SetEvent`. But suppose that had happened what you mention above, what should be the proper way to prevent such a 'lurking'  deadlock? I suppose you don't suggest not to use threads :-)

Comment: If your code is calling `SetEvent()` but `Execute()` is not reacting to it, then the most likely explanation is that your `OnWork` event handler is not exiting properly so `Execute()` can call `WaitForMultipleObjects()` again to detect the stop signal and terminate the thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`TThread.WaitFor()` waits for the thread handle (the `TThread.Handle` property) to become signaled when the underlying thread object terminates at the OS layer.  That signal happens when `TThread` calls the Win32 API `ExitThread()` function on itself after your `Execute()` method has exited (and after `TThread.DoTerminate()` has been called and exited).  What you describe sounds like you are encountering a deadlock that is preventing your `Execute()` method from exiting correctly even though you may have signaled `FStopEvent` to stop your loop.  Given the code you have shown, that means either `WaitForMultipleObjects()` is returning an error code you are not looking for, or more likely your `OnWork` event handler is not exiting correctly at times so `Execute()` can then exit itself.

All you have shown so far are the definitions of your task classes themselves, but you have not shown how they are actually being used in your project.  Please show the rest of your task logic and stop making people guess what the problem might be.

The first thing I would suggest is **take the call to `Stop()` out of your destructor**.  It does not belong there.  **NEVER** destroy a thread that is still running.  Always stop the thread first and wait for it to finish terminating before you then destroy it.  `TThread` by itself has enough problems of its own being destroyed while running, you don't need to add to that.

Comment: Your remark makes perfectly sense, were it not that I have not succeeded in isolating the code that causes the problem. And that means I have to post too much code. I hoped someone would point out the errors to me. Well you did by advising me how to stop a thread. Marjan Venema and you warned me about deadlocks in the work being executed in `Execute`. That means a careful scrutinizing and testing and probably restucturing of the code. That's harder than changing the thread code. Thanks for pointing this out to me.

Comment: This answer gave me some clues as what to search for so I decided to mark it as correct. I stop threads before destroying them. It didn't help but it yields better code. I am now looking careful through all `OnWork` event handlers.